# Display two tables select values in select option

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables (client_login,co_passenger).i want to display fname from both tables in select box.i have tryed this.but it display fname from only one table.

```
<select name="client" class="category_list" id="dynamic_select" >

  <?php
      $query= "SELECT  c.fname,p.fname FROM client_login c,co_passenger p" ;
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
echo '<option value="directory.php?cat_id='.$row['fname'].'">'.$row['fname'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>  
</select>
```

i want to display aa,bb,cc,dd in select box

client_login
[image: client_login]

co_passenger
[image: co_passenger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two queries merged together using union

```
$query= "SELECT  fname FROM client_login
union
select fname from co_passenger "
```

This will return combined results.